# Crossdomain ajax with jquery 1.5.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I have used ajax with jquery 1.4.2 on my domain, but I need to get a page from another domain. The following code works with jquery 1.4.2 but I want to use 1.5.1:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://www.domain.com/page.aspx",
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg );
    }
});
```

For some reason I get an error, but when I change to jquery 1.4.2 it works.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using CORS, or is this standard JSONP.  What does the remote page return?

Comment: Why do you want to use 1.5.1 when 1.6.2 is available? You realize they fix bugs in every release, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for crossdomain ajax jquery I'm trying http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: This is seriously not needed >= JQuery 1.5

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following header in the response (need control over both domains)

Header set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://your-domain.com"`

In your Javascript code you need to add

`jQuery.support.cors = true;`

It works at least with 1.6.2, but only in Firefox (and Chorme I think), IExplorer don't support CORS standard...